# "such + noun + like something" structure instead of "such + noun + as something" structure

Tags: grammar

I'd like to ask you if I can use **like** instead of **as** in a **such + noun + as** structure. I know that I can just use a **noun + like something** structure instead, which is simpler. But, what I would like to know is merely whether it is correct.

For instance:

> He tends to easily get close to **such** people **as** Tom.
>
> He tends to easily get close to **such** people **like** Tom. ( ← Is this correct?)
>
> He tends to easily get close to people **like** Tom.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, your *such people like* structure is not correct. It might be clearer to you if we arrange it in a way that's more natural to most modern English speakers, with **such + as** together:

> He tends to easily get close to people **such as** Tom. ← Correct
>
> He tends to easily get close to people **such like** Tom. ← Incorrect

That combination, **such like**, is only ever heard in very limited regional varieties of British English, in the phrase "and such like", meaning "and other things like that", and should really never be used by an English language learner.

Comment: Thank you for the neat answer very much! I would like to ask you one more thing about your answer. Is **people such as Tom** structure really more natural and more frequently used than **such people as Tom** structure?

Comment: Well there can be big differences between different varieties of English, but my experience with American, British, and Australian English is that **such people as** is a more formal, old-fashioned way to say it. Taking a look at Google's Ngram viewer at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+people+as%2Cpeople+such+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuch%20people%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20such%20as%3B%2Cc0, there was a dramatic change in usage in the 1970s, and now "people such as" is much more common!